# 18.04 LTS Ubuntu Software Center: Cannot resolve hostname

Tags: software-center, 18.04

I am getting the following:

```
Unable to download updates from "extensions.gnome.org":
[*/*/*/source/shell-extensions/*] failed to download https://
extensions.gnome.org//static/extensions.json: Cannot
resolve hostname
```

I am running the out of the box Ubuntu Software v3.28.1, which I agree is a nice way to manage the software on my system.

I was able to install and launch PyCharm Pro with no issues, though I may try the [snap](https://snapcraft.io/pycharm-professional) later. I was also able to install and launch [Atom](https://atom.io/),
[VLC](https://www.videolan.org/index.html), [Zoom](https://zoom.us/), 
[Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/), Google Chrome and VirtualBox without issues, so when time permits I'm guessing I need to go upstream into source code, as I'd like to understand where the error message came from and if it means anything.

The message did not reappear when I restarted the machine.

I haven't yet tried to figure out steps to reproduce.

[image: Unable to download updates from "extensions.gnome.org"]

Comment: I also faced the same problem. But after running `sudo apt update` it got fixed.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `host extensions.gnome.org` and `host extensions.gnome.org 8.8.8.8`? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I'm having a similar issue and tried running those commands. What is the expected output of these, do you have any documentation on what these should do? Thanks.

Comment: @KieranCooney: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. As suggested prior comments, I ran:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

And that seemed to fix it.