# Ubuntu Software (gnome-software) has many errors and won't show updates

Tags: 18.10, gnome-software

Here are the errors that I'm seeing...

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you tried running the commands to update and upgrade?

Comment: Any similar errors from apt / apt-get / synaptic / aptitude? "Cannot resolve hostname" is popping up, any DNS problems, finding/pinging extensions.gnome.org & cdn.fwupd.org works ok?

Comment: @Amolith I swear that I tried those commands already, but this time it looks like it may have fixed my problem.

Comment: @Xen2050 DNS works fine. HOST works fine. PING works fine.

Comment: @heynnema glad to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. [Here we go](https://askubuntu.com/q/1030370/916401)

Comment: I swear that I tried those commands already, but this time it looks like it may have fixed my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you ran it as sudo apt-get update, which is a tiny bit different and wouldn't solve your problem :)